# jbutton action, setIcon is being executed at the end of action

Tags: java, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm developing my first awt game. I'm trying to set an icon to a button when it is clicked (under some conditions). here is the concerning part of the code:

```
if (tileIsMemTile) {
        System.out.println("!!! Right Tile !!!");
        memTile.setBackground(Color.red);
        numberOfMemTilesToGuess -= 1;
        System.out.println("It rest " + numberOfMemTilesToGuess + " tiles to guess");
    } else {
        System.out.println("!!! Wrong Tile !!!");
        Icon falseTileIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("wrong.png"));
        memTile.setIcon(falseTileIcon);
        wrongGuessAction();         
    }

    System.out.println(">>> Action processed >>>");

    if (numberOfMemTilesToGuess == 0) {
        System.out.println("\n END OF THE LEVEL");
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed all the tiles without error !! \n");

        dispose();
        //TODO  !!!! SHOW INTERLEVEL INFORMATION !!!!

        if (memGridDimX != maxDimX && memGridDimY != maxDimY) {
            if (memGridDimX == memGridDimY)
                new Memory(memGridDimX, memGridDimY + 1);
            else
                new Memory(memGridDimX + 1, memGridDimY);
        } else
            System.out.println("You have a really good memory my friend!");
    }
}

private void wrongGuessAction() {
    //TODO !!! FAILED IN LEVEL MESSAGE !!!

    try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (Exception e1) {}
    dispose();

    if (memGridDimX == initialDimX && ( memGridDimY == initialDimY || memGridDimY == initialDimY + 1))  
        new Memory(initialDimX, initialDimY);
    else
        new Memory(memGridDimX - 1, memGridDimY - 1);
}
```

So here after i set icon of the jbutton, i want to see it before disposing the old jframe and launching the new one (next level in the game). but despite of trying to delay of executing *dispose()* function by:

try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (Exception e1) {}

and with any other delaying functions (such as comparing currenttimemillis(), to-t1), i even tried to use;

```
memTile.setBackground(Color.green);
int i = 0;
do {
System.out.println(i); i++;
} while (!memTile.getIcon().equals(Color.green));
```

actually last one seems to be working but eclipse jumps to debug mode without any exception and it doesn't kill the process even i close the frame.

So nothing works. In each case the frame closes and i cannot see the icon on the button. if i comment dispose and leave it to create next frame, the old frame stays, icon loads on button and new frame is being created. I couldn't understand the principle of execution of setIcon method.

Thanks in advance.

//          memTile.setBackground(Color.green);
//          int i = 0;
//          do {
//
//              System.out.println(i); i++;
//          } while (!memTile.getIcon().equals(Color.green));

Answer (score 2):

The `ActionListener` is invoked on the AWT event dispatch thread. The same thread also processes any other events like paints. Thus, as long as your `actionPerformed()` method not returns, nothing is painted (or anything else on the GUI is changed).

You should do longer-running actions outside of this thread (i.e. start a new Thread doing this), and then for GUI changes later call back with `EventQueue.invokeLater` (or `EventQueue.invokeAndWait`).

Comment: i was turning around in a one single class, i will use another one to call the main class and then i will try wait & notify methods. I must learn more about EventQueue. by the way, thank you very much Paŭlo Ebermann for your quick reply.

Comment: I found a quick fix for this icon refresh thing "update(getGraphics());", it works fine for me, maybe it helps to others too.

Comment: No, that's not a good solution.  Better to fallow Paulo's and Uhlen's recommendations (1+ to each)

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann  when i use _SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait_ the code goes in debug mode showing class EventDispatchThread.run() line:172. and it locks. the program is still running. It comes in the second execution of the same code. So i put _if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread( ))_ before concerning code and it enters this case in the second times of execution. Does it mean that the main thread is still running or my subthread is running? i couldn't clearly understand from [link]http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Comment: The *andWait* version waits until the EDT had the time to execute your runnable, and only after your runnable finished, the *andWait* method returns. I don't know what you are doing in the Runnable (maybe add it to your question).

Answer (score 1):

Paŭlo Ebermann gives the correct answer but I just wanna add that **never sleep on the Event Dispatch Thread!** That only makes things worse. Swing is powerful toolkit, but it's tolerance to incorrect threading (sleep on EDT, update UI outside EDT) is IMHO number one reason why people have trouble with Swing. If it instead would fail with *RuntimeException* under such circumstances a lot of bugs would be exposed and thus more easily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> I must learn more about EventQueue.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Maybe your Thread.sleep(...) code should be replaced with a Swing Timer. The Swing tutorial also has a section on "How to Use Swing Timers".